# What is the correct way of multiple dispatches to the thunk in Redux from the componentDidMount of a React Component?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, thunk

As the title suggests, I'm trying to dispatch multiple actions from the same component's `componentDidMount` hook.

**MovieDetails.js**

```js
class MovieDetails extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const movieId = this.props.movieId
    this.props.dispatch(fetchMovieDetails(movieId))
    this.props.dispatch(fetchMovieImages(movieId))
    this.props.dispatch(fetchMovieActors(movieId))
  }
```

All the actions are quite similar. Here's an example of one.

```js
export const fetchMovieActors = movieId => {

  const movieActorsUrl = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/${movieId}/475557/credits?api_key=${apiKey}`

  return async dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: "FETCHING_MOVIE_ACTORS_START" })
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(movieActorsUrl)
      console.log(res)
      dispatch({
        type: "FETCHING_MOVIE_ACTORS_SUCCESS",
        data: { movieActors: res.data }
      })
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch({
        type: "FETCHING_MOVIE_ACTORS_FAILURE",
        error: { error: "Something went wrong" }
      })
    }
  }
}
```

I'm just asking is this the correct way of doing this ?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/frontend-bootcamp/tree/master/bonus-servicecalls/demo

Comment: Can you please elaborate?